# AttributeError 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'

Tags: python, json

Im getting this error while executing my code TypeError: string indices must be integers. Before that im doing the same thing but its working.

```
for con in bin3 ['content']['annotations']:
print(con) #This loop is working fine.
```

This is my python code

```
 import pandas as pd
import json
filename = 'new4.json'
for line in open(filename, 'r'):
print(line)
for item in filename['content']['transform']: #this loop is not working
print(item)
```

This is my json file

```
{
"content": {
  "transform": [
     {
        "ID": 5,
        "class": 6,
        "createTime": "",
        "name": "Source",
        "advancedProperties": [
           {
              "ID": 82,
              "class": 12,
              "name": "Tracing",
              "value": "Normal"
           }]
        }]
              }
 }
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

Correct way to use a JSON file in Python is to convert it into a Dictionary first - `json.load()` does it for you

```
import json
filename = 'new4.json'
with open(filename) as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
print(data['content']['transform'])
```

NOTE: Your Json file is not in Right Format - Closing Braces are missing

Correct JSON Format:

```
{
"content": {
  "transform": [
     {
        "ID": 5,
        "class": 6,
        "createTime": "",
        "name": "Source",
        "advancedProperties": [
           {
              "ID": 82,
              "class": 12,
              "name": "Tracing",
              "value": "Normal"
           }
         ]
      }
    ]
}
}
```

Comment: im getting this error                                                                                                              
JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 14585 column 1 (char 573628)

Comment: Something wrong with your JSON - All the keys and values which are strings must be enclosed in double quotes . I think your JSON data is very HUGE.

Comment: YES , but i tried to get some json objects in that file using for loop.